# In Laravel 5, What's the difference between {{url}} and {{asset}}?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I find sometimes both is OK?  So what's the really difference?

For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('resources/views/admin/style/css-ui.admin.css')}}">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('resources/views/admin/style/font/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
```

these two form is both OK.

So, what's the differences?

Answer (score 37):

## Deciding which [URL helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#available-methods) to use

Consider the type of URL that is needed / how the URL is being used. One of the advantages of having separate helper methods for each type of URL is they can have different handling logic. For example, assets (e.g. CSS, images, etc.) could involve a check that the file exists in the file system but do not require the type of analysis that a route would because the route may have parameters.

### [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) Generates an absolute URL to the given path [(code)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L159)

- Use for static URLs (which should be rare).
- Accepts array of parameters that are encoded and added to the end of the domain.
- Preserves any [URL query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Example).

  ```php
  {{ url('search') }}
  // http://www.example.com/search

  {{ url('search', ['qevo', 'laravel']) }}
  // http://www.example.com/search/qevo/laravel
  ```

### [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) Generates a URL to an application asset [(code)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L210)

- Use for files that are directly served such as CSS, images, javascript.
- Only accepts a direct path.

  ```php
  {{ asset('css/app.css') }}
  // http://www.example.com/css/app.css
  ```

### [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route) Gets the URL to a named route [(code)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L308)

- Use for every route (every route should be named to help future-proof path changes).
- Requires [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes).
- Accepts associative array for route parameters.
- Allows override for relative route vs. absolute route (default).

  ```php
  {{ route('user.profile', ['name'=>'qevo']) }}
  // http://www.example.com/user/qevo/profile

  {{ route('user.profile', ['name'=>'qevo'], false) }}
  // /user/qevo/profile
  ```

Answer (score 12):

`{{url}}` allows you to create a link to a URL on your site -- another benefit is the fact that you can set the second parameter to an array with query string parameters within.

`{{asset}` simply allows you to link to an asset within your public directory -- for example `css/main.css`.

Comment: [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) has nothing to do with named routes.

Answer (score 2):

`URL::route` gets the URL to a named route. So in your case if you name your route like this:

```
Route::get('/account/register', [
    'name' => 'register', 
    'uses' => 'RegisterController@create'
]);
```

then you will be able to use

`<a href="{{ URL::route('register') }}" >Register 1</a>`
in Blade templates.

Comment: Probably a better answer than mine -- good examples! Thanks for building on what I wrote.

Comment: Question asks about [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) and [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset).

Answer (score 2):

**`asset()`** asset function generates a url for an asset using the current scheme of request.
**Ex : asset('images/img.png')**

**`url()`** The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path.

**Ex : url('admin/users')**