# Load bootstrap with laravel default

Tags: css, laravel

I'm sure I'm missing something here but not sure what.  According to the Laravel documentation:

> Laravel's package.json file includes the bootstrap package to help you
>   get started

According to the instructions:

> Before compiling your CSS, install your project's frontend
>   dependencies using

Following this I run `npm install`  then I run `npm run dev`
From here I test it out using a simple form in a blade file called '`options.blade.php`
In my blade file I load assets like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/app.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('assets/css/app.css')}}">
```

My expected results would be that the bootstrap css would be usable "right out of the box".  The layout appears with no css style loaded.
I can confirm `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` exists.

This is specifically related to using bootstrap as Laravel says preset.  I know how to add the css links from cdn or local if needed but wanted to do it out of the box with Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you're giving `url()` the wrong paths.

If your assets are `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js`, you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/app.css')}}">
```

(You may want to use `asset()` instead of `url()` here, too. See [In Laravel 5, What's the difference between {{url}} and {{asset}}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217975/in-laravel-5-whats-the-difference-between-url-and-asset) for details.)